# Is it possible to do REST without XML representations?

Tags: xml, rest

I want to know whether it is possible or not to represent resource in rest without xml. Please give some logic against answer.

Comment: Most people use JSON.

Comment: ... Yes?  What does XML have to do with REST?  Why would you think the two are linked together?

Comment: If you know what REST means, the answer is obvious. If you don't know what REST means, the answer won't do you much good. This is related to Armstrong's Tautology.

Answer (score 2):

A nice overview of all the types supported by REST can be found in the MediaType class in the package javax.ws.rs.core:

- application/xml
- application/atom+xml
- application/xhtml+xml
- application/svg+xml
- application/json
- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- application/octet-stream
- text/plain
- text/xml
- text/html

Most common are XML and JSON however

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of REST is that the choice of payload data sent in requests and responses is completely flexible.

You can choose to offer XML, JSON, XDR, CDR, Protocol Buffers, ASCII, EBCDIC, YAML, your own custom scheme, you name it. Well-designed RESTful APIs - and the application protocol they usually use, HTTP - offer a clean layer of separation between the payload format and everything else needed to communicate.

Best of all, REST gives clients the ability to negotiate to their preferred payload format as a "free" part of the application protocol. In HTTP's case, it's done with [Content Negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). Your API might then choose to offer its services in say either JSON or XML, and leave it up to the client to request their preferred encoding using the `Accept` header in its requests. If the API server can meet the client's request to communicate using its preferred encoding, the server will do so.

Answer (score -1):

It is entirely possible to represent data without XML.

For example:

> > > > ```
> > > > 42
> > > > ```

Comment: You know, there's one thing you can post in a comment thread that's more tiresome than "Me too". Guess what it is? Also, you didn't answer the question in any way that's informative to somebody clueless enough to ask the question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: What? (fixed typo)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have no idea what you are talking about.